# phoenix: render template of other folder

Tags: templates, web-deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two template folder in my web/templates folder:

```
> ls web/templates
personal_info       user
```

What I want is to render some template from `user` folder in another view of `personal_info`. so I have a file at path: `web/templates/personal_info/index.html.eex`, I have following content:

```
<%= render "user/xyz.html" %>
```

But I get following error:

```
[error] #PID<0.821.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError) Could not render "user/xyz.html" for MyApp.PersonalInfoView, please define a matching clause for render/1 or define a template at "web/templates/personal_info". The following templates were compiled:

* index.html
```

Please tell me how do I render template defined in other folder, I tried few permutations, but none worked.

Comment: See https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#sharing-views-and-templates in the guides. The link above and some of the answers are outdated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Phoenix templates are just functions, so when you want to render your `UserView`'s "xyz.html" template from your `PersonalInfo`'s view, you just call the function!

Let's say you are inside the `web/templates/personal_info/show.html.eex` template. (`Phoenix.View.render` is already imported for you):

```
<%= render UserView, "xyz.html", user: user %>
```

Of if you want to pass along all the template assigns that your PersonalInfo template was provided:

```
<%= render UserView, "xyz.html", assigns %>
```

As you found, this works from anywhere, because templates are Just Functions. For example, the same thing would work in iex:

```
iex> Phoenix.View.render(MyApp.UserView, "xyz.html")
"<h1>User ..."
```

Comment: On Phoenix 1.3.0, I had to add `alias MyApp.UserView` into `web/views/personal_info_view.ex` or else it'll say `(module UserView is not available`

Comment: @owyongsk where is this file now? It looks like it no longer exists past phoenix 1.3.0?

Answer (score 4):

As of Phoenix `1.5.1`

Phoenix matches controllers, views, and templates by names. It can be changed by [put_view](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_view/2) like:

```
conn
  |> put_view(MyAppWeb.SpecialView)
  |> render(:show, message: "Hello")
```

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/3-views

Comment: this is the way! :)

Answer (score 2):

For me worked when I specified application name:

web/templates/product_gallery/index.html.eex:

```
<p>Please, render me!</p>
```

web/templates/kitchen/index.html.eex:

```
<%= render APP.ProductGalleryView, "index.html", assigns %>
```

If I am trying to render without application name I am getting:

```
undefined function ProductGalleryView.render/2 (module ProductGalleryView is not available)
```

Comment: In your `lib/web/views/kitchen_view.ex`, you can also add `alias APP.ProductGalleryView` so you can just use render ProductGalleryView

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Phoenix 1.3.0. Seems like I had to add

```
alias MyApp.Userview
```

to `web/views/personal_info_view.ex`, then

```
<%= render conn, UserView, "xyz.html" %>
```

---

Without the alias above, then you have to

```
<%= render conn, MyApp.UserView, "xyz.html" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently following worked:

```
<%=  Phoenix.View.render(MyApp.UserView, "xyz.html") %>
```

please let me know, If there are better alternatives.

Source: [this](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.7.2/docs/templates#section-shared-partials).